# Anyone has link for sample J2EE application which uses Oracle database to deploy into weblogic

Tags: weblogic

I need a sample application to test weblogic. It should also use Oracle Database .
It would be helpful if it has the steps for deployment process.

TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

The WL Server already contains Sample Applications (I used the generic install from the oracle homepage: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html )

Here is a screenshot from the Installation Assistant, sorry for it being german. The circled are says "Complete with examples". Select that during the installation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need other than the sample application given.